# How do I create the correct XML type request using SOAP in PHP?

Tags: php, xml, web-services, soap

I am trying to post the following XML to a providers API using SOAP in PHP. In order to return an availability response.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <soap:Body>
        <CheckAvailability xmlns="https://domain.org/webservicesAvailabilityChecker/">
          <availabilityRequestInput>
            <UserLogin>
              <Username>user@domain.co.uk</Username>
              <Password>password</Password>
              <Client>1234</Client>
            </UserLogin>
            <RequestDetails xsi:type="NumberRequest">
              <ItemNumber>012345678910</ItemNumber>
              <Stockcode>ABCD1234</Stockcode>
              <CDCode />
            </RequestDetails>
          </availabilityRequestInput>
        </CheckAvailability>
      </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>
```

The XML when inputed using the .NET client Webservice Studio validates the XML input and returns the correct anticipated response. So I know that the XML in the example is good, it works.

However when trying to post the same request using PHP SOAP, my PHP request causes a PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Internal Server Error

My PHP code for the request is as follows:

```
    $client = new SoapClient('https://domain.org/AvailabilityChecker.asmx?WSDL');

    $params = array(
        'availabilityRequestInput' => array(
            'UserLogin' => array(
                'Username' => 'user@domain.co.uk',
                'Password' => 'password',
                'Client' => '1234'
            ),
            'RequestDetails' => array(
                '_' => array(
                    'ItemNumber' => '012345678910',
                    'Stockcode' => 'ABCD1234'
                ),
                'xsi:type' => 'NumberRequest'
            )
        )
    );

    $result = $client->CheckAvailability($params);

    echo '<pre>'.$result.'</pre>';
```

It seems to me that the "RequestDetails" type is causing the error. As when I omit the RequestDetails type I get a valid error code back from the API, telling me that I've omitted the Request object. No matter what I try I can't get the format of this correct.

We already use this same providers API's for two other long standing SOAP queries and they work just fine. Can anyone see where my input is going wrong? All help is greatly appreciated.

Note: The "CDCode" in the XML example is optional and it's omission or inclusion makes no difference to the response.

**Update:** Since submitting this question I've given up on using the method above and have succeeded by using cUrl instead. The following code will fetch the anticipated response with no issues whatsoever and with very little latency.

```
<?php   
$url = 'https://domain.org/AvailabilityChecker.asmx?WSDL';
$referer = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$xml = '<?xml ver...'; // As example above.

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referer);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 240);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type:text/xml; charset=utf-8','Accept: application/xml','Cache-Control: no-cache','Pragma: no-cache','Content-length: '.strlen($xml)));

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$response = stripXMLNameSpace($response);
$output = simplexml_load_string($response);

echo '<pre>'.$output.'</pre>';
?>
```

So whilst this has solved the problem for me, unfortunately I still don't understand why my first method does not work.

I also had to write the following little function to strip out all the namespaces from the XML response sent back, otherwise loading the result into an object with simplexml_load_string(); will fail in this example. Although this depends on what your XML response is made up of.

```
function stripXMLNameSpace($input) {
  $output = str_replace('soap:Envelope', 'Envelope', $input);
  $output = str_replace('xmlns:soap=', 'soap=', $output);
  $output = str_replace('xmlns:xsi=', 'xsi=', $output);
  $output = str_replace('xmlns:xsd=', 'xsd=', $output);
  $output = str_replace('soap:Body', 'Body', $output);
  $output = str_replace('xsi:type=', 'type=', $output);
  $output = str_replace('xsi:nil=', 'nil=', $output);
  return $output;
}
```